# how to use mmap to access a (linux module) character device's variable in user space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, mmap

I am trying to create a test module - a character device that will respond to calls from the user.
up until now the module worked well  - responded to read, writes and ioctls.

the overall idea is this: create a variable in the module, and be able to read/write (through mmap) to this variable.

this is the kernel code (narrowed down):

```
static char *hwevents;

static struct file_operations testmod_fops = {
.write = t_write,
.open = t_open,
.unlocked_ioctl = t_ioctl,
.read = t_read,
.mmap = t_mmap,
.owner = THIS_MODULE
};

static int t_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
    {
    unsigned long phys = virt_to_phys(hwevents) << PAGE_SHIFT;
    printk("test!\n");
    pr_err("started mmap func\n");
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, phys, (vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start), vma->vm_page_prot))
        return -2;
    pr_err("finished mmap func\n");
    vma->vm_ops = &simple_remap_vm_ops;
    simple_vma_open(vma);
    return 0;
}

static int __init testmod_init(void)
{
    int i;

    printk("I am here\n");
    misc_register(&testmod_miscdev);

    hwevents = (char *)get_zeroed_page(GFP_KERNEL);
    if (hwevents == NULL) {
        pr_err("hwevents allocating failed\n");
        return -1;
    }


    return 0;
};
```

this is the userspace code:

```
int memory_map_hub()
{
    int fd;
    void *mp = NULL;
    if(fd = open("/dev/testmod", O_RDWR) == -1){
        printf("error opening file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    mp = mmap(NULL, 8, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (mp == (void *)-1) {
        printf("failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("the address returned is %p\n", mp);


    munmap(mp, 8);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

2 things that doesnt work:

first - the mmap() function always returns (-1).
second - the printk()/pr_err() inside the mmap function in kernel space doesnt work.

it seems as if the mmap function in kernel space doesnt even launch and automaticly returns -1.

thanks

edit: this is the answer - [ENODEV error in MMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909949/enodev-error-in-mmap)

Comment: You can only `mmap()` a regular file, AFAIK. When `mmap()` fails, you could check for `ernno == EACCES` to see if that was the problem.

Comment: i can't believe i've spent so much time searching for the problem and it was this.. the answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909949/enodev-error-in-mmap